# Checkbox in datatable not working while submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

The design of my page has a form comprising a textbox at the top contained in a div element. Beneath that I have datatable with a checkbox in each row of the table. This entire form is in turn contained in another div element around it.

In this case, whenever I submit the form with some value in the textbox above and selecting one of the rows by checking the checkbox, the checkbox value is not getting passed through the form submission.

If I remove the div element around the textbox above and put the entire form 
in a single big div, it works. However, I have constraint here that I can not 
remove the inner div containing the textbox. I can not explain why I have such constraint since this is just a simplified and to-the-point version of my requirement.

I am also including the CGI Perl code along with a runnable code below, in the form action just the current script only needs to be called :

```
enter code here
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $qry = new CGI;

&main();

sub main {
    $qry->header();
    my $body = &display_page();
    print $body;

}

sub display_page {
    my $url = "current_script.cgi";


    print '<pre>' . Data::Dumper::Dumper( \%{$qry->Vars}) . '</pre>';

    my $checked1 = "checked" if defined $qry->param('First') || '' ;
    my $checked2 = "checked" if defined $qry->param('Second') || '' ;
    my $checked3 = "checked" if defined $qry->param('Third') || '' ;

    my $html .= qq{<br>
   <div>
  <div>
  <form name='myForm' action='$url' method=post>\n};
  $html .=  $qry->textfield(-name=>'TEXT_FIELD',
    -default=>'Enter your text here',
    -size=>35,
    -maxlength=>50);
  $html .= "<br><br> </div>";


  $html .= qq{
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src ="/js/testchkbox.js"></script>
};

$html .= qq{
    <table width = "90%" border="1" >
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="container" >
    <table id = "test" class="display compact cell-border table-bordered stripe row-border order-column" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
        <td>Check</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Address</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "1st" $checked1></td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>11-22-15</td>
        <td>London-101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "2nd" $checked2 ></td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>11-22-15</td>
        <td>London-101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "3rd" $checked3></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>11-22-15</td>
        <td>London-101</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    };
 $html .=  <<END;
@{[ $qry->submit(-name=>'STORE', -value=>'Submit') ]}

END

$html .= "</form><br></div>";
return $html;

}
```

```js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#test').DataTable({
        bInfo: true,
        bSort: true,
        bFilter: true,
        scrollX: '100%',
        scrollY: '475px',
        paginate: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        dom: '<"toolbar">frtip',
        oLanguage: {
        "sSearch": "Search"
        },
    });

    /* client side csv export button */
    new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            text: 'Export',
            className: 'export btn btn-sm btn-success'
        }]
    });

    /* add the button to the div with class name toolbar */
    table.buttons().container().find("a").removeClass( 'btn-default' );
    table.buttons().container().appendTo( $('div.toolbar') );


    /* use the below button in case we need to fetch the data from server side */
    /*
    var bootstrapButton = "title='Export data into CSV' class='export btn btn-sm btn-success' role='button'"
    $("div.toolbar").html("<a href='" + window.location.href + "/csv'" + bootstrapButton + ">Export</a>");
    */

});
```

```css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

```html
<pre>$VAR1 = {};
</pre><br>
    <div>
    <div>
    <form name='myForm' action='current_script.cgi' method=post>
<input type="text" name="TEXT_FIELD" value="Enter your text here" size="35" maxlength="50" /><br><br> </div> 
     
    
    
        <table width = "90%" border="1" >
        <tr>
        <td> 
        <div class="container" >
        <table id = "test" class="display compact cell-border table-bordered stripe row-border order-column" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="skyblue"> 
            <td>Check</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>DOB</td>
            <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "1st" ></td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>11-22-15</td>
            <td>London-101</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "2nd"  ></td>
            <td>Sam</td>
            <td>11-22-15</td>
            <td>London-101</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name = "Second" value = "3rd" ></td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>11-22-15</td>
            <td>London-101</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="STORE" value="Submit" />

</form><br></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write your html like this:

```
<div>
<form name='myForm' action='current_script.cgi' method=post>
    <input type="text" name="TEXT_FIELD" value="Enter your text here" size="35" maxlength="50" /><br><br>
</div>
```

This breaks the code. Your browser doesn't really know where the form ends and therefore the checkboxes don't get submitted.

If you need a `div` around your "textbox", put it around your "textbox" like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="TEXT_FIELD" value="Enter your text here" size="35" maxlength="50" /><br><br>
</div>
```

In general check your html for syntax errors (https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Ok, but what if I need the div around the textbox plus the textbox has to be inside the form ? I need the div inside the textbox because the background area color  of the textbox would be different than that of the datatable beneath. And also the textbox value needs to be passed during form submission.

Comment: Well, the just put the div around the "textbox" and put all that inside the form. I don't see any problem there. Just don't break the syntax. And your CSS styles will be applied by classes that you give to the respective elements. If you don't understand what I´m saying, I recommend you watch some tutorials that cover the basics of HTML and CSS.